# How to remove period in Middle Initial ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have two table that 1 table need to find a match on the other table.

Say I have table1 and Masterfiles table. Table1 has a name field the same with Masterfiles.

But table1 name field has different value because it has only middle initial while Masterfiles has middle name.

Now I want to get the other field value from Masterfiles called "Gender", since table1 has no value on gender field.

The table look like this:

```
Table1                              Masterfiles

Name             Gender             Name                      Gender
Smith, John E.                      Smith, John Estaw         M
Canard, Donald R                    Canard, Donald Reever     M
```

Since I have a lot of records in table1 that need to get the value of gender field I need to do it programmatically.

Currently I have the following code:

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset

Dim strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Table1")

Do While Not rs.EOF
    strSQL = "SELECT [Name], Gender FROM Masterfiles WHERE [Name] Like '%" & Me!txtName & "%'"

    Set rs2 = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

    If rs2.RecordCount > 0 Then
        rs!Gender = rs2!Gender
    End If
Loop
```

But this code will not get any result because some of the value of Name field in table1 has a period in the middle initial while other row has no period. Please refer to the sample data above. The middle initial of "Smith, John" has period while "Canard, Donald" has no period.

So how can I query Masterfiles and get the value of Gender field and put it in table1 gender field?

Comment: You may want to flag records as exceptions if rs2.recordcount > 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
 strSQL = "SELECT [Name], Gender FROM Masterfiles WHERE [Name] Like '%" & replace(Me!txtName,".","") & "%'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the name in VB; it is best just to use VB to remove any `.` from the end of the name before searching:

```
Dim searchName as String

If Me!txtName.Substring(Me!txtName.Length - 1,1) = '.' Then
    searchName = Me!txtName.Substring(0,Me!txtName.Length - 1)
Else
    searchName = Me!txtName
End If

strSQL = "SELECT [Name] FROM Masterfiles WHERE [Name] Like '%" & searchName & "%'"
```

However, in the long term you should probably fix your design:

- Give each person a numeric ID that is the same in all tables.
- Split the name into first, middle, and last fields.
- Use a single table to store all information that is unique to the person.  Then link it to other tables using the ID.